# help me in apex class to get account to list

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page Controller="togetaccounts"  action="{!accountlist} >
    <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                    <apex:selectList value="{!Acclist}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}">
                        </apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectList>
          </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class togetaccounts {
    public String Acclist{get;set;}
    Public Account accountlist{get;set;}
    Public list<selectoption> options{get;set;}

    public togetaccounts () {

    }

    public PageReference accountlist() {

        options = new list<selectoption>();
        options.add(new selectoption('','--None--'));
        for(Account a :[select Id,Name from Account])
            {
            options.add(new selectoption( 'a.Name','a.Id'));
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some detail about what the problem is?

Comment: Changing `options.add(new selectoption( 'a.Name','a.Id'));` to `options.add(new selectoption(a.Id, a.Name));` is the first thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use controller's constructor than having another call to controller through **action="{!accountlist}"** attribute on page.

Please find the other way to implement this below:

```
<apex:page Controller="togetaccounts">
    <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                    <apex:selectList value="{!Acclist}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}">
                        </apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:selectList>
          </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

```
public class togetaccounts {
    public String Acclist{get;set;}
    Public Account accountlist{get;set;}
    Public list<selectoption> options{get;set;}

    public togetaccounts () {
        options = new list<selectoption>();
        options.add(new selectoption('','--None--'));
        for(Account a :[select Id,Name from Account])
            {
                 options.add(new selectoption( 'a.Id','a.Name'));
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the options list generation logic to it's own getter method:

```
public class togetaccounts {
    public String Acclist{get;set;}

    public togetaccounts () {

    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List();
        for (Account a :[select Id,Name from Account])
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption(a.Id, a.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

And remove the PageReference method altogether, you don't need an action page method either.